# Helm3 Panel Database Login Error

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an old Windows 2003 server using the Helm3 control panel (now owned by Parallels). Today it suddenly started displaying the following error when accessing the panel:

```
Cannot open database "helmdb" requested by the login. The login failed
```

The only relevant material I found online was this:
http://webhostingneeds.com/Cannot_open_database_"helmdb"_requested_by_the_login._The_login_failed

However, this does not accurately describe the problem. In fact, in the Helm Configuration Tool, the DB connection was successful and no problems were reported.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was with the DB itself, which entered "suspect mode". I followed the following guide:

http://mahedee.net/recovering-sql-server-database-from-suspect-mode/

to recover from suspect mode.

This requires SQL Server Management Studio Express to be installed on the server (or the ability to connect remotely).